# Automatically play audio on website after delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I tried changing state play from `false` to `true` and also tried adding ComponentDidMount, ComponentDidUpdate, ComponentWillMount but nothing worked. I kept getting an error at some point.

It works fine when clicking the play and pause button but I want it to play automatically after 2 seconds when someone visits the site.

**My code:**

```
import React from "react";
class Music extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { play: false };
    this.url = "http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3";
    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
  }
  //   componentDidMount = () => {
  //     this.togglePlay();
  //   };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(this.setState(this.togglePlay()), 500);
  };
  togglePlay() {
    this.setState({ play: !this.state.play });
    console.log(this.audio);
    this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.togglePlay}>
          {this.state.play ? "Pause" : "Play"}
          {/* {this.state.play ? "Play" : "Pause"} */}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Music;
```

**Error:**

```
index.js:1582 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.


   at B (index.js:1582)
    at G (index.js:1899)
    at index.js:1914
    at index.js:1933
    at index.js:1414
B @ index.js:1582
G @ index.js:1899
(anonymous) @ index.js:1914
(anonymous) @ index.js:1933
(anonymous) @ index.js:1414
music.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
togglePlay @ music.js:22
Music._this.componentDidMount @ music.js:16
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:16998
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:18512
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:18717
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20247
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20170
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:20075
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:20049
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:19904
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19711
scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:20415
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:20441
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20509
push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render @ react-dom.development.js:20820
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:20974
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:20292
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20970
render @ react-dom.development.js:21037
./src/index.js @ index.js:16
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:782
fn @ bootstrap:150
0 @ routes.js:17
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:782
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: Why do you call togglePlay inside setState(). You should just call it like normal

Comment: Please don't: start playing music if the user indicates they want to hear it. Don't hijack someone's audio.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the timeout-function like:

```
setTimeout(this.setState(this.togglePlay()), 500);
```

Why don’t you just call the togglePlay function like the folllowing:

```
setTimeout(this.togglePlay(), 500);
```

That is why you are also experiencing an error.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` method can be use only to set the state of the component.
if you want more information look the documentation of [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

if you want to trigger your `togglePlay` function a little bit later, just pass your method `togglePlay` to `setTimeout` with a delay in ms.

for example:

```
// this.setState({ play: !this.state.play });
setTimeout(this.togglePlay, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit hard to wrap your head around, but `setTimeout` accepts a *function* and a number. What you've passed to it is essentially `void` and 500. Lemme better explain it:

```
function test() {
    return true;
}

setTimeout(test(), 500);
```

This may throw an error because I'm calling the function, rather than passing a function. So, in effect, I'm passing `true` and 500 to the `setTimeout` function.

You can try the following:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => this.togglePlay(), 500);
    // Or setTimeout(this.togglePlay, 500); if you get what I'm trying to say
};
```